# A Quotient of Free Group

Tags: free-groups

If $F$ is a free group on a finite set $S$, then the squares in $F$ generate a normal subgroup $N$ and $F/N$ is elementary abelian $2$-group of order $2^{|S|}$.

Let $F$ be free group on infinite set $S$, and $N$ the normal subgroup generated by squares in $F$.

> **Q.** $F/N$ is infinite direct *sum* or *product* of $|S|$ many copies of $\mathbb{Z}_2$?

Comment: I'm not sure about the first statement itself, namely that the squares in $F$ generate a *normal* subgroup $N$. Or do you mean $N$ is the smallest normal subgroup containing the group generated by squares?

Comment: Since $F$ is composed of finite words, I would bet on the direct sum.

Comment: @joriki Oh, got it. I was assuming that $N$ is generated by the squares of the generators.

Comment: @Seven: They do generate a normal subgroup, as e.g. $g^{-1}aabbg = \left(g^{-1}ag\right)\left(g^{-1}ag\right) \left(g^{-1}bg\right) \left(g^{-1}bg\right)$.

Comment: @Steven: *generate* mens take all possible products of squares in $F$; we certainly get a subgroup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could conclude easily by saying that since the words are finite, then you must be in the direct sum and not the direct product as Quang Hoang points out.

But I think the most adequate point of view in general is that of universal properties (it's the most helpful in general cases) : $F$ has the universal property the any function $f:S\to G$ to a group $G$ extends uniquely to a morphism $\tilde{f}: F\to G$. Then the quotient $F/N$ has the property that any group morphism $\tilde{f}: F\to G$ such that $\tilde{f}(a)^2 = 1$ for all $a\in S$ factors uniquely to a morphism $\overline{f}:F/N\to G$.

So $F/N$ has the property that any function $f:S\to G$ such that $f(a)^2= 1$ for all $a\in S$ extends uniquely to a group morphism $\overline{f}: F/N\to G$.

This is exactly the universal property of $\bigoplus_S \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, since such a function $f:S\to G$ is the same as giving a morphism $f_a: \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\to G$ for all $a\in S$.

So $F/N$ and $\bigoplus_S \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ have the same universal property : they are canonically equal.